# Export time series plot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, time-series, seaborn

I am running the following code to export a .png file in Python:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
sns.set_style('ticks')

plt.figure(figsize=(30,15))
ax = ts['Item'].plot(lw = 10)
ax.set_xlim(pd.Timestamp('2019-09-01'), pd.Timestamp('2019-12-12'))
plt.xticks (rotation=45)
plt.title('Time Series of submitted items',fontsize = 30)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.savefig('TimeSeries.png',format="png")
```

The exported .png file is empty though.

The `ts dataframe` contains three columns and is grouped by date. 
Calling `head` I get the following information:

```
Submit date time    Item        Status
2019-01-09          2           2
2019-01-10          224         224
2019-01-11          196         196
2019-01-12          337         337
2019-02-09          9           9
```

I have put `plt.show()` behind `plt.savefig()`, but still encounter this problem. Apart from this I am wondering, whether it is smart to explicitly define the date range with `pd.Timestamp` or whether I should format the submit date time column.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that you have data within your date range ? (which is not the case in the sample you provided). You might have mixed date formats.

Otherwise, the following snippet should work :

```
ax = df.plot(x='Submit date time', y='Item', lw=10, figsize=(30, 15))
ax.set_xlim('2019-01-01', '2019-12-12')
plt.xticks(rotation=45)
plt.title('Time Series of submitted items', fontsize=30)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Note that you don't have to specifically format/convert the date in `set_xlim`.

Comment: Thanks for the snippet !! The issue is caused that the submit date column is wrongly formatted, as it is `yyyy-dd-mm', but it should be `yyyy-mm-dd'. I have changed it using `dataset['Submit date date'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')`, but the grouping still unfortunately shows the submit date date as above :/

Answer (score 0):

The code below plotted correctly for me. I think the issue was that the plot command wasn't giving enough information to the plot function. See [dataframe plotting][1]. Also, the xlim command of your original code was starting in September vs Jan.

````
plt.figure(1)
#format the data types
ts['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(ts['Date'])

ax = ts.plot(x = 'Date', y = 'Item')
ax.set_xlim(pd.Timestamp('2019-01-01'), pd.Timestamp('2019-12-12'))
plt.xticks (rotation=45)
plt.title('Time Series of submitted items',fontsize = 30)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.savefig('~/python_files/TimeSeries.png')```


  [1]: https://datatofish.com/plot-dataframe-pandas/
````

Comment: Hi @DeathbyGreen, thank you for the snippet. I have found my mistake. I did not correctly specify the format, formatting the original date string into the timestamp. I have corrected it to `dataset['Submit date time'] = pd.to_datetime(dataset['Submit date time'],format='%d-%m-%Y')`. Now I received the plot and could also save it.